# How could I make the notification icon disappear when user clicks on notification action?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I receive notification on reply action 
I'm answering using action `INTENT.SEND`  using gmail 
but I want the icon could be disappeared ,when user clicks on action in notification part.
I know I can cancel the icon by cancelling the notification when it receives in `Activity` the notificationId , but in my case I'm just using the standard Intent which I could not handle.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
        PendingIntent dismissIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this.getApplicationContext());
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) 
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) 
            .setContentTitle("Message from test")
            .setContentText("message")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Dismiss", dismissIntent)
```

Comment: which icon? did u mean to remove notification?

Comment: the small icon that appears on the top part of the phone,and you realized you have new notification and when you open and click on action I want the small icon could be removed /disappeared.